# Firebase realtime database crash when android application used offline

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase offline database for my android app, in PreferenceScreen and load dynamic config data.

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
```

Using it as:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(fireBaseReference);
```

I am using it as per tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

App works fine when it is connected, on offline it is crashing with below stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.nishant.starterkit.mock. 
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your app has multiple process. Make sure you initialize firebase database only through Context of your application.

```
    if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
```

You should initialize firebase DB as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, How to check if my app is multiprocess or not ?